# Sort the lines of a file with alphanumeric words

Tags: linux, shell, sorting

I have 2 loops which create some folders that contain words that begin with 0,1,..,26 each.

(e.g.

file 0 contains:

```
0yes 

0no
```

file 1 contains:

```
1yes

1no
```

....

file 26 contains:

```
26yes

26no
```

Those show the files, but the words inside are not sorted.

```
file=$1
directory=$2
```

I made this final loop, where file is the file that contains some text, and directory is the directory that contains the file.

```
for i in {0..26}; do
        echo The file "$i" from Directory $2 contains:
        cat "$i"
done
```

Where should I place the `sort -d` ? Because they are alphanumeric words, I must use `sort -d`.

Comment: I'm not getting what you're trying to accomplish here; too much ambiguity. Did you create directories prefixed by numbers so that you could iterate the directories in order? The entire `echo` string should be quoted, not just `$i`. You're `cat`ing a number and not the actual file since `$i` is the index of your `for-loop`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the files themselves are not to be changed, just replace `cat` with `sort -g`.